# Snowy display when connecting Yamakasi Catleap to 2018 MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, external-display, dvi, usb-c, thunderbolt

I'm trying to connect a [MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2018, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports)](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP775?locale=en_US) to a [Yamakasi Catleap Q270](https://kostasfsworld.wordpress.com/catleap-q270-led-ergotron-mx-arm/), using a [Club3D CAC-1510](https://www.club-3d.com/en/detail/2471/usb3.2_gen1_type_c_to_dual_link_dvi_d_hdcp_on_version_active_adapter_m-f/) USB-C to Dual Link DVI-D adapter.

When I connect the monitor, I get clear video for a split second, after which it turns snowy.

I've tried:

1. Connecting the Q270 monitor to a different laptop, a M1 MacBook Pro (14-inch, 2021). **This worked**, so it's probably not an issue with the monitor, DVI-D cable, or USB-C to DVI-D adapter.
2. Connecting the 2018 MBP, via a USB-C to MiniDP adapter, to another 4K monitor. **This also worked**, so it seems like the laptop generally works correctly.
3. Power cycling the 2018 MBP, as well as resetting its SMC and NVRAM. This did not help.
4. Trying different Thunderbolt ports on the 2018 MBP. None of them worked.